# XamlParseException: Attribute in custom control missing, but it's defined!

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-2.0

I *sometimes* get the following exception for a custom control of mine:

`XamlParseException occurred` `Unknown attribute Points in element SectionClickableArea [Line: 10 Position 16]`

The stack trace:

```
{System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: Unknown attribute Points on element SectionClickableArea. [Line: 10 Position: 16]
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
   at SomeMainDialog.InitializeComponent()
   at SomeMainDialog..ctor()}
```

The element declaration where this happens looks like this (the **event handler** referenced here is defined, of course):

```
<l:SectionClickableArea x:Name="SomeButton" 
    Points="528,350, 508,265, 520,195, 515,190, 517,165, 530,120, 555,75, 570,61, 580,60, 600,66, 615,80, 617,335, 588,395, 550,385, 540,390, 525,393, 520,385" 
    Click="SomeButton_Click"/>
```

This is part of the code of `SectionClickableArea`:

```
public partial class SectionClickableArea : Button {

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PointsProperty
        = DependencyProperty.Register("Points", typeof(PointCollection), typeof(SectionClickableArea),
            new PropertyMetadata((s, e) => {
                SectionClickableArea area = (SectionClickableArea) s;
                area.areaInfo.Points = (PointCollection) e.NewValue;
                area.UpdateLabelPosition();
            }));
    public PointCollection Points {
        get { return (PointCollection) GetValue(PointsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PointsProperty, value); }
    }
```

I use this control for something like a polygon-shaped button. Therefore I'm inheriting from button. I've had similar problems (`E_AG_BAD_PROPERTY_VALUE` on another `DependencyProperty` of type string, according to the line and column given, etc) with this control for weeks, but I have absolutely no idea why.

---

Another exception for the same control occurred this morning for another user (taken from a log and translated from German):

```
Type: System.InvalidCastException Message: The object of type System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl could not be converted to type [...]SectionClickableArea. at SomeOtherMainDialog.InitializeComponent()
    at SomeOtherMainDialog..ctor()
```

Inner exception:

```
Type: System.Exception Message:  An HRESULT E_FAIL error was returned when calling COM component at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
    at MS.Internal.XcpImports.SetValue(INativeCoreTypeWrapper obj, DependencyProperty property, DependencyObject doh)
    at MS.Internal.XcpImports.SetValue(INativeCoreTypeWrapper doh, DependencyProperty property, Object obj)
    at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetObjectValueToCore(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
    at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueInternal(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, Boolean allowReadOnlySet, Boolean isSetByStyle, Boolean isSetByBuiltInStyle)
    at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueInternal(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
    at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
    at System.Windows.Controls.Control.set_DefaultStyleKey(Object value)
    at System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl..ctor()
    at System.Windows.CoreTypes.GetCoreWrapper(Int32 typeId)
    at MS.Internal.ManagedPeerTable.EnsureManagedPeer(IntPtr unmanagedPointer, Int32 typeIndex, Type type, Boolean preserveManagedObjectReference)
    at MS.Internal.ManagedPeerTable.EnsureManagedPeer(IntPtr unmanagedPointer, Int32 typeIndex, Type type)
    at MS.Internal.ManagedPeerTable.GetManagedPeer(IntPtr nativeObject)
    at MS.Internal.FrameworkCallbacks.SetPropertyAttribute(IntPtr nativeTarget, String attrName, String attrValue, String attachedDPOwnerNamespace, String attachedDPOwnerAssembly)
```

Any ideas what's wrong with the control, or what I can do to find the source of these exceptions? As I said, these problem occur only every few dozen times the control is instantiated.

Comment: Since this is now a popular question, I wanted to follow up: In this case, we never found the problem. It's been quite a while since I worked on this, but I think a team member "solved" it by calling the constructor for the object for the XAML Root Node in a loop, repeating until no exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

I've also came across this issue. I do not have a good explanation for that (seems to be XAML parse bug), but I've fixed it by adding following code to XAML:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
   <customNamespace:InheritedControl x:Name="dummyInstance"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no XAML expert but are you missing a namespace on Points (e.g. l:Points)?

Answer (score 0):

I think that we are seeing the same problem.  I just get the invalidcast exception more frequently. When, through blind commenting of stuff, I can suppress the invalidcast, I do sometimes get the attribute missing error for an attribute that is, in fact, there.  Have you found a solution?

BTW: the easy way to repro it is to just load the offending app and repeatedly hit F5 to refresh the page.  You will get it eventually.

I have also seen an intermittent InvalidOperationException that is through from DependencyObject.get_NativeObject().

see my SO question here:
[Intermittent InavlidCastException in a UserControl.InitializeComponent()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470942/intermittent-inavlidcastexception-in-a-usercontrol-initializecomponent)

See my silverlight.net bug report here:
http://silverlight.net/forums/t/67732.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case error was on one of members. Exception was thrown on members constructor.
I solved it by putting breakpoint before InitializeComponent() method and on debug mode pressed F11 to Step Into and found error.
Hope this will help.
Thanks.

Comment: There definitely was an exception, see my comment to the original post. But is was pretty much random, as you can tell by our "solution" to the issue. Thanks for the info though.